# Select specific values from json_decode in php

Tags: php, angularjs, json, web-services, decode

I've stumbled on a problem that i think is a bit strange since i've followed other examples to the exact code but i still didn't get the same result.

**Short summary**

I'm developing a shopping application and i'm using a session for the cart. Since i want to have the possibility to remove items from the cart i am using some levels inside the `JSON` object of the session.

**Cart summary**

1. The cart is created on button click

   ```
   $_SESSION['cart']["cartItems"][$product_id]=$cartProduct;
   ```

   - Where `$cartProduct` is an `array()` of items like the `product_id`, `product_name`, etc.
   - Where the cartlevel: `$product_id` is for the remove cart row `function()`.
2. The cart is then shown in an angularJS application. I will pass the full view and just show the getCart section and the JSON response.

   ```
   $json = json_encode($_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']);
   echo($json);
   ```

   - The JSON echo is:

     ```
     {"3":{"id":"3","name":"Bedrukte Jurk","price":25.99,"size":"M","quantity":"3","total_product_price":77.97},"2":{"id":"2","name":"Blouse","price":26.99,"size":"S","quantity":"3","total_product_price":80.97}}
     ```
   - The JSON is stripped by removing the `['cartItems']` value.
3. The `$_SESSION['cart']`'s original JSON object would be:

   ```
   {"cartItems":{"3":{"id":"3","name":"Bedrukte Jurk","price":25.99,"size":"M","quantity":"3","total_product_price":77.97},"2":{"id":"2","name":"Blouse","price":26.99,"size":"S","quantity":"3","total_product_price":80.97}}}

   {"cartItems":{"3":{"id":"3","name":"Bedrukte Jurk","price":25.99,"size":"M","quantity":"3","total_product_price":77.97},"2":{"id":"2","name":"Blouse","price":26.99,"size":"S","quantity":"3","total_product_price":80.97}}}
   ```

**The question**

So now i would like to select only the `"name"` ,`"id"` and other values seperatly since i have to write them to a database. it would be something like:

```
$json_test = json_decode($_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']['name']);
echo $json_test;
$product_name = $json_decode_name;
```

So at this moment my question really starts. i'm having one issue and one real question on how ould i achieve this (thinkin of using `foreach()`

So first my problem is that i can't, or i am not able to select the specific values from the `json` cart `session`. I've tried some things from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) and made a small comparison:

```
$json1 = '{"foo-bar": "123", "foo-bar2": "456"}';
echo($json1);
echo "<br>";
$obj = json_decode($json1);
print $obj->{'foo-bar2'}; // 456
echo "<br>";
$json_decode = json_decode($_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']['3']);
print $json_decode->{'name'};
echo "<br>";
var_dump(json_decode($_SESSION['cart']['cartItems']['3'], true));
echo "<br>";
$json = json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
echo($json);
```

The `$json1` is working but i can't quite get my own version working.

**Some extra tips?**

The second thing is then pushing it to the database. I was thinking about: when achieving the name / names from the `JSON` string i would use a `foreach()` statement. Something in the area of:

```
$cart_product_name = $json_decoded_name
foreach ($cart_product_name as $product_name) {
    insert_Query 
}
```

And repeat this for the id's, quantity's, etc.

If the question isn't clear please let me know in the comments and i'll edit it.

As always, Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW: `print $obj->{'foo-bar2'}; // 12345` this is not true! It prints `456`

Comment: @B001 I've updated my question